# Spring Security form login is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement the form login in spring security and the configuration is following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("amit").password(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() 
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .formLogin(formLoginConfigurer ->{
                    
                formLoginConfigurer
                    .loginPage("/api/authentication/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/api/loginSuccess")
                    .failureForwardUrl("/api/loginFailed")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login")
                    .permitAll();
            });

    }

    private Filter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception{
            return new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager());
    }
    
}
```

The AuthFilter

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
    
    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager auth) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(auth);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String username= obtainPassword(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        System.out.println("username : "+username +" and password : "+password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

I am getting the form on `http://localhost:8080/api/authentication/login` but when I submit nothing happens. I mean when you click on submit button nothing happens and you stay on the same page. In fact the request was never sent to the server at `/login` path to process the request!

**The Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HomeController {
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping
    public String statusCheck() {
        return "service is up and running :)";
    }
    @GetMapping("/authentication/login")
    public String returnLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/loginSuccess")
    public String successLogin() {
        return "You are successfully logged in";
    }
    @GetMapping("/loginFailed")
    public String failedLogin() {
        return "Incorrect username or password";
    }
```

If you want to see my form so there you go:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <h1>Login</h1>
   <form name='f' action="login" method='POST'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any template engine?

Comment: No, But I want to use this with simple html without using Thymleaf or jsp

Comment: maybe you should put `/api/login` in the `action` of the form instead of just `login`?

Comment: I had tried putting `/api/login` in the form but still submission doesn't take anywhere! I have tried removing the login processing url from the config and then changed the default login path `/login` in the form but still it doesn't change the form submission path